# Recurrence Relation In While Loop

Tags: loops, while-loop, wolfram-mathematica, recurrence

I have a Pseudo Code as below:

```
Do While i<m and j<n ;
a[i,j]=a[i,j]+a[i-1,j-1];
j=j+1;
i=i+1;
```

How can I write this in Mathematica? Can I use recurrence Relations in loops?

Comment: What are the initial conditions?

Comment: To solve one recurrence relation you might be better off starting with `RSolve`.  To solve multiple recurrence relations I'd probably start with `Map[RSolve,` and a list of relations; the last place I'd start with Mathematica is a loop.

Comment: Your equation does not make sense. It effecitvely says a[i,j]=0 for all i,j.